# Matlab: How to nest ndgrid?

Tags: matlab

Say I have three vectors `a,b,c` and want to apply a function `f` on all combinations. So I use `[A,B,C] = ndgrid(a,b,c); result = f(A,B,C)` and implement `f` using pointwise evaluation, e.g. `(A.^B).*C`.

However, there is a separate evaluation of a second function `g` that only depends on `a` and `b` but not on `c`. So a call of `G=g(A,B)` (in my example `A.^B`) would waste time by calling the function with the same arguments for `length(c)` times redundantly. I could use a separate `ndgrid`, but I want the result of `g` be stored in the same dimensions like `A,B` and `C` so I can later call e.g. `h(G,A,C)` without further modifications.

How can this be achieved, and how to not waste space by this redundancy without slowing the program down by using nested `for` loops instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just the first planes of `A` and `B` for the computation, then replicate the result with the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) to make `G` the same size as the other variables:

```
G = g(A(:,:,1),B(:,:,1));       %# Compute one unique plane of G
G = repmat(G,[1 1 length(c)]);  %# Replicate that plane for a 3-D matrix
```

**EDIT:**

If replicating `G` seems like it could be wasting memory (i.e. if you're dealing with very large matrices), then a for loop is probably a better way to go. In addition, you could try using the function [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) in your calculations. For example, to multiply the 2-D `G` by your 3-D `C`, you can do this:

```
bsxfun(@times,G,C);
```

Which would end up giving the same results as:

```
repmat(G,[1 1 length(c)]).*C;
```

Will it save on memory? That I can't be sure of, since I don't know exactly how [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) is implemented. You'll have to try it out for your specific problem to see which approach gives better speed or memory usage.

Comment: I wonder if this `repmat`ing (or using `ndgrid`) doesn't waste lots of memory by adding redundancy, or whether matlab stores this in a sophisticated manner...

Comment: ...apparently not. `a = linspace(0,1,1e3); [A,B,C] = ndgrid(a,a,a)` killed my matlab session

Comment: thanks for the update, I'll try and have a look at `bsxfun`, too. At the moment memory is probably not my main concern though, I was just curious

Comment: @Tobias: I'm not surprised MATLAB crashed on you, since you were trying to create 3 double-precision matrices with **1 billion** elements each, leading to a grand total of around **24 GB** of storage (likely enough to crash [any system](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html#1)).

Comment: True. But I guess there are shorter command to crash matlab on purpose :-7 I did `ndgrid(a,a)` first, but I wanted to see if there was some optimization that only kicks in for larger sizes. `bsxfun` is quite useful indeed, I could e.g. let `g` be `bsxfun(@power, a', b)` without the need to create `A` and `B` at all, and use `bsxfun(@times, G, shiftdim(c,-1))` as `f`